# Convert document.referrer as a variable in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, shopify, liquid

**Goal:** is to Push the JSON to google tag manager..

**Problem is:** there is no available liquid variable for 'referrer' as per Shopify Documentation.

**Possible Solution:** is to create a variable using Javascript

So what I did is:

1. I created a script that will append the URL website where the visitors came from.
2. capture the appended website URL and convert it to variable
3. Put the variable `{{ ref }}` to the JSON

When I inspected the element the 'referrer'(JSON) doesn't have any value

please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = document.referrer;
    $(".referrer").append(content);
});  
</script>

{% capture ref %}
<div class="referrer">Referrer: </div>
{% endcapture %}


<script type="text/javascript">  
dataLayer.push({
  ‘userEmail’ : ‘{{ customer.email }}’,
  ‘productCategory’ : ‘{{ collection.title }}’,
  ‘productName’ : ‘{{ product.title }}’,
  ‘price’ : ‘{{ sca_price | money }}’,
  ‘originalPrice’ : ‘{{ sca_price | money }}’,
  ‘cartItems’ : ‘{{ cart.item_count }}’,
  ‘currency’ : ‘{{ shop.currency }}’,
  ‘referrer’ : ‘{{ ref }}’, // not working
  ‘productRating’ : ‘’,
  ‘reviewCount’ : null,
  ‘event’ : null
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a Shopify Variable to find referrer. You don't need to even capture it in a page variable and use it. Just update:

```
‘referrer’ : ‘{{ ref }}’, // not working
```

to

```
‘referrer’ : document.referrer,
```

Edit:

Use the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    push_data = {
      'userEmail' : '{{ customer.email }}',
      'productCategory' : '{{ collection.title }}',
      'productName' : '{{ product.title }}',
      'price' : '{{ sca_price | money }}',
      'originalPrice' : '{{ sca_price | money }}',
      'cartItems' : '{{ cart.item_count }}',
      'currency' : '{{ shop.currency }}',
      'productRating' : '',
      'reviewCount' : null,
      'event' : null
    }
    push_data['referrer'] = document.referrer;
    console.log(push_data); //remove this code. This is to only check referrer is populated
    dataLayer.push(push_data);  
</script>
```

Comment: not working, when I inspect the element it shows prntscr.com/joep3g , it just says ‘referrer’ : document.referrer,

Comment: you can check the element here: https://ellanacosmetics.myshopify.com/collections/eyes/products/copy-of-charm-loose-multipurpose-pigments?variant=12924200747050

Comment: The quotes that you are using is wrong. Use doublequotes instead of quotes you are using now. Javascript does not recognise those quotes. Remove the document load code that you are using.

Comment: if this is the double quote you are talking it is still not working :( http://prntscr.com/jofdey

Answer (score 0):

Simply use JavaScript:

`"referrer": document.referrer`

Comment: not working, when I inspect the element it shows http://prntscr.com/joep3g

Comment: check this. and try to inspect the element
https://ellanacosmetics.myshopify.com/collections/eyes/products/copy-of-charm-loose-multipurpose-pigments?variant=12924200747050